# Keep getting back an empty array when its being called Swift 2

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift2

I'm trying to append vidar to videoArray and it works but only with in the Alamofire block. When i try to get the count out side of it I get a return 0 but in side the `Alamofire` block i get back 5. Im guessing it has to do with the scope? Im calling the function `getFeedVideos()` inside my `viewDidLoad`.

```
let APIKey = "AIzaSyBF1fGTvY4Z73jNBRFlxiSDelt4zqMnNCg"
var videoArray = [VideoObj]()

// main function
func getFeedVideos (){

    // Fetch video data
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems", parameters: ["part":"snippet", "playlistId": "PL8kma_GjQgWzBLAciqmwC4duAPcSRyt8T", "key":APIKey], encoding: ParameterEncoding.URL, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in

        var vidar = [VideoObj]()

        if let value = response.result.value {
            var arrayofvideos = [VideoObj]()

            // loop
            for videos in value["items"] as! NSArray {

                let videoObject = VideoObj()

                videoObject.videoID = videos.valueForKeyPath("snippet.resourceId.videoId") as! String
                videoObject.videoTitle = videos.valueForKeyPath("snippet.title") as! String
                videoObject.videoDescription = videos.valueForKeyPath("snippet.description") as! String
                videoObject.vidoeoThumbUrl = videos.valueForKeyPath("snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url") as! String

                arrayofvideos.append(videoObject)

            } // For loop ends

            //print(arrayofvideos.count) // Prints out 5, which is correct
            //print(arrayofvideos[0].videoTitle) // Prints out video title


            //  P A R S E  print("JSON: \(value)")

            //

            vidar = arrayofvideos


        }  // If Statement ends


        print(vidar.count) // prints 5
        self.videoArray = vidar
        print(self.videoArray) // prints array

    } // AlamoFire Ends


    // ** Anything in there returns 0 ** //



    print("\(videoArray.count)  count ") // But this array prints out 0 !?!?
    //print(arrayofvideos[0].videoTitle) // No title "fatal error: Array index out of range"


} // Function End
```

Comment: I could keep finding duplicates, but the heart of the issue is that `.request` is an asynchronous operation, which means that the results are not available until some (significant?) amount of time after the routine returns.

Comment: @DavidBerry Thanks for finding those dupes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this has to do with the scope of your variable `videoArray`. The scope of `videoArray` is local to the `getFeedsVideos()` function. This is the case for `vidar` as well. To increase the scope of these variables you can move them to the instance level by declaring them at the top of the class.

Comment: That alone won't solve his problem.  `.request` is executed asynchronously, the print etc after the call to `.request` are executed before the request is actually performed.

Comment: Thank you @DavidBerry. If he executes the request synchronously, will everything else (all threads) wait until the request has returned, before proceeding?

Comment: He shouldn't execute synchronous net operations inside of viewDidLoad, and, I'm not sure that Alamofire can be used synchronously anyway.  Better to just look at one of the 98 other questions asking the same thing.

Comment: Alamofire cannot be used synchronously (without extensive hacking).

Comment: @AaronBrager you don't need hacking for a particular request only, a plain-old semaphore would suffice :)